# Help is these inequalities in Conway's complex analysis book true?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 116 he writes:

[image]

I have two questions:

1. I didn't understand why there is such $M$. What I know is if $f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$, then $\lim_{z\to 0}zf(z)=0$.
2. If there is such $M$ why is the last inequality true?

Comment: For the second part of your question, see [Jordan's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma) and the [estimation lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma)

Comment: @user170231 Thank you! in which course do we study these lemmas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are both a standard part of any introductory complex analysis course around the time you learn about the residue theorem, or at the very least singularities. Possibly under a different name?

Comment: "$f(z)$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$" means "there exists a continuous function $g(z)$ such that $g(z)=f(z)$ whenever $z\ne0$. Choose such a $g(z)$ for $\frac{e^{-z}-1}z$. Then $g(z)$ is continuous on the closed disk $\{|z|\le 1\}$, hence attains a maximum value there.

Comment: @user170231 I didn't find it in my Conway's complex analysis book

Comment: @GregMartin yes, of course. Thank you very much! Wait don't you mean $\frac{e^{iz}-1}{z}$?

Comment: yep sorry for the typo